# Spark SQL - Hivecontext - Datacopy from one table to another table in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am copying data from one Hive table to another Hive table(External) in Spark SQL code for the data volume 74 million rows (~50 GB). The insert operation is taking more than 40 mins.

> ```
> hiveContext.sql("insert overwrite table dev_work.WORK_CUSTOMER select * from  dev_warehouse.CUSTOMER")
> ```

I have tried the other data copy ways such as:

1. hdfs -cp for these external tables:

> `hdfs dfs -cp hdfs:/home/dummy/dev_dwh/CUSTOMER
>   hdfs:/home/dummy/dev_work/WORK_CUSTOMER`

2. Export Import :

> ```
> export table dev_warehouse.CUSTOMER to 'hdfs_exports_location/customer';
> import external table dev_work.WORK_CUSTOMER from 'hdfs_exports_location/CUSTOMER';
> ```

Cluster details:

CDH 5.8 , 19 Node Cluster

Could you please help to tune the performance to find any alternate way to perform fast data copy.

Thanks,
Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying `Hadoop DistCp` which is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html